# Maven2: can we have dependency for a plugin thats used in the build section

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

I am using a project's open source that consists of a set a parent POM and 
several children POM. Those children POM represent libraries, arch-types and
a plug-in. This plugin depends on various of these children modules and is 
used within the  section of dependent projects like mine.I have imported 
this Maven project to my Eclipse workspace.

In my own project's POM (also in Eclipse) I can reference those modules via 
dependencies without a problem. However I would also like to use the plug-in in 
the build section but it cannot be used due to the following Maven2 error:

`Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.grouplens.lenskit:lenskit-eval-maven-plugin:2.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.grouplens.lenskit:lenskit-eval-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-SNAPSHOT`

This is because I am accessing the POM's directly via Eclipse's "resolve dependencies
from workspace projects" and of course this snapshot version has not been deployed to
a repository so this is the only way I can actually use it.

I tried:

1. Add any of the dependencies of lenskit-eval-maven-plugin:
   Their are several but I just added the only one of the project's
   module (others include stuff like maven-plugin-api):

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.grouplens.lenskit</groupId>
       <artifactId>lenskit-test</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. placing a dependency for that plugin module before using the module in the  section

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.grouplens.lenskit</groupId>
     <artifactId>lenskit-eval-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${lenskit.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. adding a dependencies in the plug-in itself so:

   ```
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>lenskit-eval-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <groupId>org.grouplens.lenskit</groupId>
           <!-- TODO -->
           <version>${lenskit.version}</version>
           <extensions>true</extensions>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.grouplens.lenskit</groupId>
                 <artifactId>lenskit-eval-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>${lenskit.version}</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
   ```
4. And using (0), (1) and (2) at the same time

Ok, so I realize that attempt (2) is pushing it. So my question is: is their
any way I can use a plug-in in the build section that is also a dependency? 
If so how? If the use of solution (1) is correct, could this be an issue with
Eclipse's method of resolving to local workspace first?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing artifact for maven2 from its default repo. Try adding explicit repo or this plugin is not suitable for maven2 (check this for maven3, I dont have any problems).

Comment: this is a snapshot that has not been deployed to a repository, so no Maven repo available. I am working on the code so that it can later be deployed. I am currently using Eclipse's "resolve dependencies from workspace projects" to use the code. This "workspace repo" is found and does work (as seen the project's build path). I think it is an issue with the Maven POM. My question pertains to the POM and not the repo.

Comment: I mean repo, from which maven downloading dependencies. You can add this using <repository> or <pluginRepository> tags. You should read about maven basics [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/)

Comment: That's just it. I don't have a repo. I only have a local maven project. I was hoping that the Eclipse m2e could deal with this as it does the other dependencies. It reports the above error. For now I am going to use the repo version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a `<pluginRepository>` in your `settings.xml` or in POM for your snapshot version of the plugin, because plugins are not being searched in normal repositories.

**UPDATE**

Your local maven repo is an auto-created cached version of online repos under `$HOME/.m2/repository`.

`-SNAPSHOT` versions which are deployed to Central repo are usually stored on some other address, which must be explicitly set. Adding this should help to use the snapshot version if you don't have this in your POM/`settings.xml`:

```
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
  <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
  <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
  <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: I don't have a repo. I only have a local maven project. I was hoping that the Eclipse m2e could deal with this as it does the other dependencies.

Comment: Hope I don't sound ungrateful but I repeat: I only have a local Maven project. I am working on the SNAPSHOT code. It is only available on my disk as a Maven project. I cannot deploy it either (not the owner of the project). So I assume that I cannot use your example above. I do think I can create my own local repo and then use the URL for this.

Comment: Yes, sorry for misconception. I re-read your original post: _and of course this snapshot version has not been deployed to a repository so this is the only way I can actually use it_. If I get this right, what stops you from installing this plugin to your local repo with `mvn install` in the parent POM?

Comment: I don't own the project and cannot mess with the POMs. I suppose I could alter the POM locally and manually deploy it to my local repo. But the whole issue really is that I was hoping the me2 plugin would find this dependency just as it finds the normal ones. I could then alter and test the code without the need to change POMs and manually install the modules. I figured a configuration change in my project POM (not the modules) would do it. Maybe I am just asking for too much 8-(. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Yes, you could download the project (and that's what I thought you did) and run `mvn install`. If I understand your situation, my example above with `<pluginRepositories/>` would work with your current setup. This is the snapshot repo which used at their project and it's publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

In [maven central you will not find any snapshot version](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Clenskit-eval-maven-plugin) of such things only release. In your case you need to use a different version of the plugin like this:

```xml
<groupId>org.grouplens.lenskit</groupId>
<artifactId>lenskit-eval-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2</version>
```

which is of Sep. 2013...

The thing which you mentioned in your question like this:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>lenskit-eval-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.grouplens.lenskit</groupId>
        <!-- TODO -->
        <version>${lenskit.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.grouplens.lenskit</groupId>
              <artifactId>lenskit-eval-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${lenskit.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies
```

does not make sense, cause you define a plugin where you like to add the same plugin onto the classpath of the plugin.

The only thing which will bring you to solve the problem is using the right version like this:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>lenskit-eval-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.grouplens.lenskit</groupId>
        <!-- TODO -->
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <...>
      </plugin>
      ...
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please see my response to the other other answers.